# Printing Images To Zebra Printer

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl, powerapps

I'm creating an App using PowerApps and i have a flow that uses data from my PowerApps SQL database.

This flow creates a .lbl file which i can then print as and when necessary.

The issue i have is that the data passed to the flow to create the file includes a Photo (Image) that's stored in an Image data type field within my SQL table.

The Photo doesn't print on the label, I've used Labelary viewer as an example, this is attached.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

[image: Screenshot of the label]

Comment: What printer driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using the printer driver TTP145C.

Comment: If you can, try the Bartender driver. It handles images on Zebras very well.

Comment: I've tried that @TerryCarmen and I still don't get any output. I'm assuming that the SQL field i'm using isn't correctly formatted.

Comment: Can you post the code where you render the page for the printer, including where you add the image?

Comment: It won't allow me to post the label file text as there are too many characters. Which is a shame.

Comment: I'm not familiar with powerapps, but generally speaking, you need to build the page including the image in a container of some sort like an imagebox or document, the use the object's print functionality to actually send it to the printer. If you're trying to print images directly, you can check Zebra's site for examples. https://developer.zebra.com/thread/34489